# Why the value of a pointer to int can't be the value of a pointer to a const int?

Tags: c

Why is this incorrect? The problem is when assigning `b = p` I get the following warning: `assignment discards 'const' qualifiers from pointer target type`.

```
int a = 4;
int *b;
const int *p = &a;
b = p;
```

Comment: You're loading a hot pointer from a cool one. Why?, and what were you expecting? Was your intent for `p` to be a pointer to const-int, or a const pointer to int? The latter shouldn't flag a warning, but the former will deservedly do so.

Comment: So I have a function that  returns a pointer to a const char, and I need to get that string, but when I declare a pointer to char  and I try to point that pointer to the pointer to const char, that error appears, I think that the only method would be to make strcpy... edit: the const can not be deleted because that function is already created by another programmer

Comment: A pointer to const-data should not be used in a pointer to non-const data context. Either the source of your pointer needs to change, or the called-from code needs to adapt. You said, "I need to get that string" - there's nothing about the pointer to said-same being a pointer to const that prevents that.

Comment: You can add `const`ness without warnings (you promise not to change the value from this point onwards), but you cannot remove it (you cannot go back on your earlier promise).

Comment: This is a warning, not so severe warning. As long as you understand the implications, that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

You have one pointer which is defined to point to an `int` which you allow to be changed, `b`; but you do not init it at first.

Then you introduce a pointer to an `int` which you do not allow to be changed.
And you point it to an existing `int`. I.e. "Look at that int, but don't you change it."

Then you try to assign the "don't touch this" pointer value to the "hey, have an int, do with what you like" pointer.
The compiler tells you that you are inconsistent there, that you are contradicting yourself and cannot really mean what you write into your code.

That is why it is incorrect. Because you violate the rules which you yourself wrote.

Answer (score 1):

p is a pointer to a constant int and you're assigning it to a pointer to a non-constant int.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is defined as a `const` pointer to `int`, which means it cannot be used to modify the `int` it points to.  You can initialize it from the address of an `int` that can be modified or not. Conversely, `b` is a pointer to `int` that can be used to modify the `int` it points to.  It should only be initialized from a pointer to `int` with the same ability or the address of an `int` that is modifiable. `b = p` violates this constraint, hence the warning.

Note that `b = &a` is OK as `a` is modifiable and `p = b` is OK too, only restricting `p` from being used to modify `a`.

You could attempt to silence the warning by casting `p` as `(int *)p` but it is not recommended: in this particular instance, `p` does point to an `int` that can be modified, but bypassing the const validation by the compiler makes the code less readable and more error prone.

Qualifying `p` as `const int *p` is a promise telling *I shall not use `p` to modify what it points to*. The need to break this promise is an indication that something is not properly structured in the program.

There is no *recommended* way to silence this warning, but you can simply change the code to initialize `b` from `&a` this way:

```
int a = 4;
int *b = &a;
const int *p = b;
```

With the posted order, you could casually write `b = (int *)p;` to try and silence the warning, but a good compiler such as **clang** with warnings enabled will still rightfully warn you that this cast is fishy...

If you **really** need to remove the constness and want to silence the warning that still occurs with the obvious `b = (int *)p;`, you could write this:

```
b = (int *)(uintptr_t)(const void *)p;  // avoid this!
```

Answer (score 0):

> assignment discards 'const' qualifiers from pointer target type

The above warning clearly indicates that assignment operator(`=`) ignores `const`. This is because `b` is a pointer to `non-const` `int`, whereas `p` is pointer to `const int`. You can type-cast `p` to `(int *)` to remove that warning like:

```
b = (int *)p;
```

As some has suggested typecasting is not recommended but can be used to silence the warning. But if you see the disassembly you will found that typecasting doesn't change anything.

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 4
    lea     rax, [rbp-20]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax  ;; same with/without typecasting
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]  ;; same as well
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rax
    mov     eax, 0
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

[TRY (TYPE_CASTING)](https://godbolt.org/z/1Tjz6MKhG)

[TRY (NO TYPE_CASTING)](https://godbolt.org/z/EGdajYonr)

Comment: When I make it like that, is the adress of "b" the same adress of "p"? or as the casting is made, it is a new adress? The standar of c says that a pointer can not be pointing to a const pointer but if you make a cast isn`t it like cheating?

Comment: @eltramas yes, it is blatantly cheating. That cast is highly ill-advised.

Comment: yes, it's kind of cheating, but address of both `p` and `b` are same [try](https://godbolt.org/z/616s18E8x)

Comment: *but address of both p and b*... I would write `p` and `b` **contain** the same address. IOW they have the same value but different qualifiers.